# How to replace a string by all array value using str_replace in php?

Tags: php

```
        <?php
        $a=array('1'=>'Jan', '2'=>'Feb','3'=>'Mar');
        print_r($a);
        $str ="<p>Due Month</p>";
        echo str_replace("Month","(Jan+Feb+Mar)","Due Month");
        ?>
```

Desire Output: 
       `Due (Jan+Feb+Mar)`

How can I get this output from array using str_replace function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it for your desired output. It works 100%

```
$a = array('1'=>'Jan', '2'=>'Feb','3'=>'Mar');
print_r($a);
$comma_separated = implode("+", $a);
$str ="<p>Due Month</p>";
echo str_replace("Month","$comma_separated","Due Month");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need like this?

```
$a = array('1'=>'Jan', '2'=>'Feb','3'=>'Mar');
$replaceStr = "";
foreach ($a as $months) {
    $replaceStr[] = str_replace($months, "(Jan+Feb+Mar)", $months);
}
print_r($replaceStr);
```